# How to access an Acumatica DAC extension field from VS

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project developed by a third party that extends the Contact table.
I can access the customization project and review the DAC definition "ContactExt.UsrField1" in Acumatica's customization project interface.

However, I am having issues in using the class "ContactExt" in my Visual Studio project. I cannot seem to find a way to reference it in order to use the  PXCache<>.GetExtension() method.

Answer (score 0):

Custom DAC fields added in Acumatica Project Editor are resolved at Runtime instead of Static time, at least up to version 6.1.x.

A side effect of this is that Visual Studio can't determine their static type and therefore will underline them red and report errors during the static analysis and compilation.

When IIS compiles Acumatica customizations it puts them in a runtime code DLL. If you attach the debugger to the website IIS instance (w3wp.exe) you can see the referenced Runtime code DLL: [image]

Technically, you could statically link this DLL to your project and the DAC types will be statically visible to VS static analyzer. This would allow you to use the other customization fields in your VS project by using the runtime code DLL as a static reference and compile without errors. You could also dynamically link that DLL in your VS project but both are bad solutions because it would lock the DLL file and prevent IIS from recompiling it. Runtime code DLL is also temporary and when recompiled by IIS it will have a different UID appended to it's filename, making it unsuitable for static linking and unreliable for dynamic linking.

IIS will recompile the runtime code DLL every time IIS resets or when you change the source file codes in Acumatica 'App_RuntimeCode' folder. App_RuntimeCode is the folder where the source code shown in Acumatica Project Editor goes. This is a IIS special folder made for runtime compilation.

Given these constraints, I would suggest two ways to share data types between a Runtime customization and a DLL customization:

1. If you can modify the runtime customization, create a shared DLL containing the shared data types and reference it in both customizations.
2. If you can't modify the runtime customization, you'll have to put all code that references the shared data types in a runtime customization (with Acumatica Project Editor in App_RuntimeCode). Code that doesn't reference shared data types could also be put in a DLL and added to the same customization project files. This would be an hybrid approach combining both Runtime and Static compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried different ways and found this solution: I created an extended DAC from the Contact table within my VS project and then "re-defined" the field that I needed access to (the one that is the Customization Project). So far it's working without issues. Do you anticipate any potential issues with this idea? @HB_ACUMATICA